# Elasticsearch nested query for getting threshold hit

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the nested index structure as following:

```
{
   "customersData": {
      "mappings": {
         "type1": {
            "properties": {
               "md5": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "uscan": {
                  "properties": {
                     "ibm": {
                        "properties": {
                           "found": {
                              "type": "boolean"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                      "google": {
                        "properties": {
                           "found": {
                              "type": "boolean"
                           }
                        }
                     },
                      "ebay": {
                        "properties": {
                           "found": {
                              "type": "boolean"
                           }
                        }
                     } 
                     ...
                    }
                },
               "plink":{"type":"string"}
            }
        }
     }
   }
}
```

The example data such as: `uscan.ebay.found:true,uscan.ibm.found:true,uscan.google.found:false,...`

Each record may have one hundred customers, I wanna query the found=true greater than 5 (each record at least have 5 customers found=true). Any ideas please, thanks!

Comment: Please specify the exact mapping you are using? Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reminder, I updated my question with mapping :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minimum_should_match` for this to specify the minimum number of conditions in a `should` clause that should match. Use the query below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "uscan.ibm.found": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "uscan.google.found": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "uscan.ebay.found": true
          }
        },
        ... 
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 5
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually the answer just partially answered my question. I don't wanna indicate the customers name instead of using *, such as:scan.\*.found
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "uscan.\*.found": true
          }
        } 
      ],
      "minimum_number_should_match": 5
    }
  }
}